# Scala playframework WSClient doesn't send certificate

Tags: java, scala, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to use the Scala Play framework to call an HTTPS web api that requires me to send a specific client certificate. I set the following JVM arguments:

- -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=t:/certs/mine/testtest.ts
- -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=testtest
- -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=t:/certs/mine/keystore.keystore
- -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=testtest

The truststore is working, but the certificate in the keystore is not. The keystore was created from a certificate + private key. Investigating the keystore shows the appropriate certificate is there and of type "PrivateKeyEntry".

Here's my testing code:

```
   import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits._

   private val urlLht = <url>

   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      implicit val system = ActorSystem()
      implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
      val wsClient = AhcWSClient()

      call(wsClient)
         .andThen { case _ => wsClient.close() }
         .andThen { case _ => system.terminate() }
   }

   def call(wsClient: WSClient): Future[Unit] = {
      val requestFuture = wsClient.url(urlLht).get
      requestFuture.recover { case NonFatal(t) => t.printStackTrace; throw t }.map { response =>
         val statusText: String = response.statusText
         println(s"Got a response $statusText")
      }
   }
```

Here's the error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
```

However, using openssl everything works just fine. Like this:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect <host> -CAfile <cafile> <clientcertificate>
```